# Use insertMany to insert one document in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am confused about why Mongodb needs 2 different methods `insertMany` and `insertOne` to insert data. Why just use `insertMany`? If you want to insert one document, like `{ a: 1 }`, writing like `insertMany([{ a: 1 }])` can be exactly same as `insertOne({ a: 1 })` functionally, right?

Is there any performance difference between them when just inserting one single document?

Same question about other CRUD functions, any ideas are appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple documents to insert at once and they are in an **array** then insertmany()  is faster rather than using insertone()  over and over for say 500 documents. (Think in terms of a loop in PHP or any other language vs. a one time straight operation).

There are some caveats:

1. Mongodb limits you to 1000 operations @ once. Notice it is *operations* not documents. If there a fee e more than 1000 operations Mongodb should split them up. This then of course becomes a function of available memory which can effect a lot of things (pooling) etc.
2. You must have your documents correctly formatted in an array for insertmany() to work correctly.

The basic same idea applies to all CRUD operations. It is speed but memory (as always with Mongo) is a critical factor.

Comment: I knew for multiple documents `insertMany` is definitely better, but how about for one single document?

Comment: If you have just one document at a time I would suggest `insertone()` as there is no reason to allocate the memory Mongo needs for an `insertmany()` operation. There is overhead to consider, as I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any reference or document which explain the memory usage or any other performance differences between the 2 methods?